# play framework app authentication, user management

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Following the Book App example in play 2 for scala, I now have a basic working app.
What I want now is to add some features like

- User registration
- User authenetication to access some pages

What is the best way to do it in play for scala? Should I manage it by my own? is there a plugin for that?

Answer (score 10):

**Note**: I'm the maintainer of Silhouette.

I can suggest you [Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) which is a core only fork of Secure Social with the intention to built a more customizable, non-blocking and well tested implementation.

For the first stable version there are only two open issues which must be resolved. And these issues are only future requests. There are no API changes planed. The documentation must be improved and a [sample application](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-pastebin) is started. The unit tests are also a good starting point.

If you plan to follow the authentication flow as stated by Secure Social then stick with it. It exists since more than two years and it is well tested by many companies. Otherwise take a look at Silhouette.

Comment: Do you have the same flow of SecureSocial registration ?

Comment: Silhouette doesn't have an own authentication flow. Think of a Secure Social without the GUI stuff.

Comment: that sample application link is broken

Comment: @jwill Cloudbees hibernates the application in the free account. If you wait a little bit, the application wakes up and you can test it.

Comment: Does Silhouette offer a Java API?

Comment: @robguinness Silhouette doesn't support a Java API and it's currently not planned.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Secure Social (http://securesocial.ws/)
   But it has unusual registration flow, where the user have to enter your email first, and receive link to registration form.
   However, there is a pull request that address this issue (https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/pull/260)
2. Play Authenticate
   It doesn't support Scala out of the box. But there is a workaround created by me here: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/issues/92

Both of them requires you to write the interface layer to database. An important drawback in both of them, is that you won't be able to make use of reactive database drivers like Reactive Mongo. they assume that you will return the results immediately, not a Future of the result.

Comment: Thanks Radian for your suggestions. I see many answers for securesocial. I ll try it and see if can use it for my app.

Comment: Play-authenticate doesn't seem to directly support scala projects and secure social doesn't support play 2.4.x (yet): https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/issues/556

Answer (score 2):

There is a securesocial plugin (http://securesocial.ws). Covers most common authentication methods, has registration stuff. I found it very usefull.
The drawback is it's documentation. If you want to do something a bit differ from the simplest scenarios - be prepared to read through the source code.

Comment: +Mike Thank you for referencing securesocial. Do you know an example public application using it?

Comment: @Lahniep You need source code? You could have a look at my simple todo applicaion https://github.com/mikegirkin/papersheet

Comment: I ll give it a try and see if I can use it on a basic app.